# How to reference a viewmodel's collection in custom control ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm-light

I have a custom control that contains an ItemsControl. The DataContext for the custom control is set to a viewmodel.

I would like the ItemsControl's ItemSource to point to an Observable Collection (*TimeSpanSlots*) within the view model. I currently have:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type tsvw:TimeSpanGridView}">
    <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding TimeSpanGridViewModel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type tsvw:TimeSpanGridView}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSpanSlots}">
                        <ItemsControl.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tsvm:TimeSpanSlot}">
                                <Label Content="Time"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.Resources>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Grid support:GridHelpers.RowCount="96"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>


                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding GridRow}" />
                                <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding GridRowSpan}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    </ItemsControl>     
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I can get this to work fine if I have a UserControl and change that to ItemsControl. I'm just not sure on the syntax for referencing within a ControlTemplate.

This part in particular:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TimeSpanSlots}">
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: So what is your problem? Is the ItemsSource binding not working?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be. As the data source belongs to the custom control and not the ItemsControl I thought it might need something like: ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TimeSpanSlots}" but this doesn't seem to catch either.

Comment: The DataContext is inherited by the ControlTemplate. As long as `TimeSpanSlots` is a property in `TimeSpanGridViewModel`, the binding should work.

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

I was keeping the XAML for the custom control in a separate ResourceDictionary and hadn't merged it correctly in App.XAML.

@Clemens you're right that it just inherits the DataContext. Nice!